# ReactJS Is it adviceable to update props

Tags: reactjs

Is it adviceable to change the props to load my page with fresh data.
I have a requirement where I need to load the HTML page from JSON, example given below

```
formSchema:{
 "label": "Step 1",
 "action": "Next",
  "Fields":[
       {
          "type":"text",
          "label":"First Name",
          "name":"fname"
          "value":"Abraham"
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm able to load the HTML page from the above JSON schema, but when user clicks the submit button there will a new schema loaded through ajax call. Now if I pass the new schema to my reducers can I directly replace the props with the newSchema, as I heard mutating the props is not adviceable. In such case how do I update my props only with new data.

If I do it as follows in my reducer

```
return Object.assign(...formSchema, action.formSchema);
```

I see in console the next state is shown as object instead of an array even though I load the same set of data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`componentWillReceiveProps()`** method in React to update your view with new props.

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new 
>    props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for            example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps   and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.
>
> Note that React may call this method even if the props have not changed, so make sure to compare the current and next values if you only want to handle changes. This may occur when the parent component causes your component to re-render.
>
> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may update. Calling this.setState generally doesn't trigger componentWillReceiveProps.

**It looks like this:**

```
class YourComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
     message: props.message // initial prop
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({message: nextProps.message} // updated prop
  }
   render() {
     return (
      <div><h1>{this.state.message}</h1></div>
    )
   }
}
```

**Note:** In this code you're not updating/mutating props, instead you're using new props (nextProps) and updating the state of your view.

Comment: Thanks worked... I think i tried componentWillReceiveProps in a wrong way previously